# What structure to represent Directed Acyclic Graph in .NET?

Tags: .net, dictionary, tree, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm considering representing a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) as `Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of Integer))`
Where the key will be a vertex ID and the List will contain all target vertices along edges.

I will use this structure later to:

derive lists of possible ascendant and descendant paths

derive lists of possible next paths and possible source paths

derive a list of leaf nodes

validate proposed edges between vertices

Topologically sort vertices

Is there some problem with my approach? How have you done it in the past?
Thanks

**EDIT**
One issue with my approach is that finding **source paths** to vertices is an expensive operation, as it requires iteration over the entire dictionary. Perhaps it's in my interest to make a `DAGVertex` object exposing `Targets` and `Sources`

Comment: Is "DAG" the acronym for "[Directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can represent the graph as two dictionaries – one for incoming edges and one for outgoing ones. This will double the time to modify the graph and memory consumption, but lowers the time complexity of getting a list of edges coming to a certain vertex from `O(V + E)` to `O(1)`.

Getting a list of leaf nodes could be done similarly – just have a list of current leaf nodes (or `Dictionary(Of Integer, Boolean)`). Add a node to it whenever it becomes a leaf node, and remove it if it stops being one.

Comment: Yes, I had considered this as well. Good suggestion. Setbacks include duplication of data across two dictionaries: outgoing edge for vertex A is incoming edge for Vertex B which is just two similar dictionaries just having their keys/values swapped

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I would create entities to my nodes, and use then OOP on my approach.

If your requirements will never change and youre totally sure about that, maybe your approach is OK, but if you might have requirement changings, like for example assign "weights" to every path between a node and another, I believe It could be to difficult to do it. (would solving it by doing something like;

```
Dictionary<Int32, List<Int32, Dictionary<Int32, Int32>>
```

???)

I think my class would look a bit like this;

```
public class GraphNode
{
    private Int32 value;
    public Int32 Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
    }

    private List<GraphNode> siblings;
    public ReadOnlyCollection<GraphNode> Siblings
    {
        get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<GraphNode>(siblings); }
    }

    public void AddSibling(GraphNode node)
    {
        if (this == node)
            throw new Exception("Can't assing a node to itself as a sibling");

        if (this.siblings.Contains(node))
            throw new Exception("This node is already contained in the siblings list");

        this.siblings.Add(node);
    }

    public GraphNode(Int32 value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.siblings = new List<GraphNode>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I considered using a list of my own entity for the dictionary value but I was concerned about the cost of unboxing my data from them just to find target edges.

Comment: No, I am validating relationships between DB records using their PK Autonumbers.